# How to convert *.ts (MPEG-TS I guess) video file to WMV or MP4 using any Windows tool

Tags: windows, video, conversion, avi, mpeg

I have a banch of *.ts files I have problem playing on Windows Media Center extenders. How could I convert them to WMV or DivX AVI or MP4?

Thank's a lot.

Comment: What is the source of the .ts files? Is it a DVB card?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html#Dnload).

Quote from their page:

> If you need a simple, yet very
>   efficient tool to convert (encode) or
>   play any Multimedia file,
>       without reading manuals or spending long hours training, then
>   SUPER © is all you need.
>       It is a Multimedia Encoder and a Multimedia Player, easy-to-use with 1
>   simple click.

It's capable of converting virtually any format and has tons of extra features and options. It also supports batch **drag & drop** encoding. I use it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

While Super is a good video converter it's not that newbie friendly. I would reccomend the free Handbrake (make sure you get the 0.9.3 version if you want to save to .avi). While mainly used for ripping DVDs it can be used to encode files to .avi, .mp4 or .mkv.

Answer (score 1):

If the source of the *.ts files is a DVB card then the files may have non-compliant GOP structure and/or sync issues.

You will need to re-mux them into a normal MPEG file, [PVAStrumento](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/PVAStrumento) and [ProjectX](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ProjectX) are tools to do this. (ProjectX requires Java)

If they are from any other source I recommend [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) or [MeGUI](http://mewiki.project357.com/wiki/MeGUI:Main_Page) for conversion.

EDIT: Just found another DVB stream tool - [TS-Doctor](http://www.cypheros.de/dvb_e.html)

> Cypheros TS-Doctor is designed
>   recorded DVB transport stream to check
>   for errors and, if possible, make it
>   as compatible as it can to play it
>   back without studdering or picture and
>   sound delay. The program tries to
>   change as little as possible in the
>   original stream in order not to create
>   additional incompatibilities. PAT and
>   PMT be adjusted and non-existent PIDs
>   deleted from the tables. The picture
>   and sound streams will be analysed and
>   displayed. Not needed streams will be
>   deleted. The program has a detailed
>   review of H264 and MPEG2 video
>   streams, AC3 and E-AC3 audio streams
>   through CRC check.